# How to use dynamic quick action when app is closed [swift]

Tags: swift, dynamic, shortcut

How to use dynamic quick action in swift?
i am able to trigger my methods if the app is in multitasking. but if the app isn't running in background it doesn't work.
i am setting up my quick actions in applicationWillResignActive / sceneWillResignActive.
i am handling my methods in:
"func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)"
and
"func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)"

any suggestions?

Comment: The `performActionFor` method is only called when the app is running (in the background0.  If it is not you need to check for shortcuts when the app starts in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.  The shortcut item will be in the launch items.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer. I am afraid i am too stupid to Check for Shortcuts in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions tho

Comment: Added as an answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performActionFor method is only called when the app is running (in the background0. If it is not you need to check for shortcuts when the app starts in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or willFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The shortcut item will be in the launch items.

Something like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if let shotcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem{
        handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem)
    }

    return true
}
```

Obviously the `handleShortcutItem` is a method that will actually process the shortcut and do what you want.  You should be able to use the same one for both cases.

Comment: thank you again. seems to make sense, but it doesn't do anything so far.

Comment: Difficult to say why without knowing what you have done.  One other thing is that if you have a SceneDelete it should go in there instead.

Comment: Not handling the shortcuts in SceneDelegate was the mistake. You are my Hero!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

for the scene delegate you can use this code:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
   //check if there tapped shortcut item when app was closed
   if let shotcutItem = connectionOptions.shortcutItem {
      //do something with shortcutItem
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).